# How can I display posts' comment?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

***should I give id for posts?  How Laravel know which comments belong to which post?***

**This is my controller** :

```
public function show($id){
  $posts=Post::where('id',$id)->get();
  return view('user',compact('posts'));
}
```

**This is my blade**  :

```
@foreach($posts->comments as $comment)
    <div class="comment-form">
        <section class="post-body">
            <p>{{  $comment->description  }}</p> <!--  burda ilisdim -->
        </section>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

So I built polymorphic relations about comments. but I don't know how to use it.

***UPDATE***

***here is my Post Model***

```
    public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
}
```

}

Comment: You would have `hasMany - belongsTo` relation in post model. share your DB schema stucture.

Comment: Share your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the relation on **Post** model, as like :

```
public function comments()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Then you can access like this :

```
@foreach($posts->comments as $comment) // $posts->comments will call your comments() function
     {{  $comment->description  }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: it should be hasMany relationship.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon, my bad, its a silly mistake. I edited. Thank you

Comment: Undefined variable: $posts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\site\resources\views\user.blade.php)

Comment: @qayaxan_eyvazli your blade is `user.blade.php` ?

Comment: yes it is. is problem about $id? because how Laravel know which posts' comment display? and i built polymorphic relationship with Post and Comment model. is it true?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you doing something wrong. Please replace your code with below:
To Get Single post you have to replace code with given below in controller

```
public function show($id){
  $posts=Post::where('id',$id)->first();
  return view('user',compact('posts'));
}
```

Comment: Actually, if you look at the code, `$posts` is a single post. The naming of variables and weird fetching makes this hard to see (it should be `$post = Post::find('id');` instead of `$posts=Post::where('id',$id)->get();`, or better yet - use ModelRouteBdinging). Since its a single post, but in a collection - so you don't really have to loop it, just use `first()` on it.